# MCSession takes a long time to dealloc

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

I'm using Multipeer-Connectivity.

When the session ends, the app comes to the main menu and all network stuff is released then deallocated.

But my dealloc method is called in main thread and the `MCSession` object takes a very long time to release itself, I don't know why, and consequently the main menu screen freezes.

If somebody know why `MCSession` could be so long, I'm interested. But if it comes from the MCSession itself, is it a good solution to do this?

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    //... other release

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [_session release];
        _session = nil;
    });

    [super dealloc];
}
```

**EDIT:** nope, it's definitely not a good solution, because it makes my app crashing. Anyway, other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `[_session release]` since _session is an Ivar, the compiler will replace this line by `[self->_session release]` and the block will retain `self` instead of the iVar `_session`.
Here you have 2 problems:

1. Trying to retain an object(self) which are deallocating.
2. When the queue will be executed, it'll call self which is already deallocated.

The following solution create a local variable which point to the same address as the iVar and release it inside the block, the block will not capture self.

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    //... other release
    MCSession* localSession = _session;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [localSession release];
    });

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: "can you explain why does this work?" - MCSession normally operates on the main thread.  It takes a long time to disconnect and that is what it does before it releases.  During that long time the main thread is blocked.  By placing this task on a separate thread the main thread is not blocked and your app continues while MCSession blocks its new thread. Alternatively you could put your next task on a new thread.  Blocking a thread does not prevent the next lines of code from executing - but there will be no animations like UIAlerts or presentViewController

Comment: As you can see, the solution i proposed is just to avoid to try to retain self (using the iVar) inside the dealloc which is a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

*bsarr007's* solution will work for non-ARC projects. If you are using ARC, you can try this:

```
__block MCSession *localSession = _session;
_session = nil;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    oldSession = nil;
});
```

It works for me. What I am doing here is increasing reference count of `MCSession` object by creating new local variable that points to that object, so it won't be deallocated immediately when setting `_session = nil`. After that I am running asynchronously the code that decreasing reference counter of my `MCSession` object using background queue.

Comment: Yes, my solution like the question is for non ARC project.